# Using generic interface repository

Tags: c#, .net

I have my repositories setup like below.

```
interface IRepository<T> where T : DataRow
{
  T Get(int key);
}

interface ICartonRepository : IRepository<CartonDataRow>
{

}

class CartonRepository : ICartonRepository
{
  public CartonDataRow Get(int key)
  {

  }
}
```

I also have a PackRepository which is defined in the same way as the CartonRepository. What I would like to do is something like the following.

```
IRepository<DataRow> repository;
switch (rowType)
{
  case Carton:
    repository = new CartonRepository();
    break;
  case Pack:
    repository = new PackRepository();
    break;
}
```

Is there a way I can achieve this?

Comment: What you have is perfectly fine in theory, as long as you have a valid way of determining how the concrete repository maps to the 'rowType' you've come up with. Is there something specific which isn't working?

Comment: Not sure I understand the intent - if you declare repository as IRepository<DataRow>, then the calls to its Get method are going to return a compile-type type of DataRow and not one of its subclasses.  In such a scenario, you might as well just drop the generic from IRepository and have it return DataRow :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For C# 3.5 you will have to add the following:

```
public interface IRepository {
   DataRow Get(int key);
}

public abstract class Repository<T> : IRepository<T>, IRepository
    where T : DataRow
{
   public abstract T Get(int key);

   DataRow IRepository.Get(int key) {
       return this.Get(key);
   }
}
```

Then change `CartonRepository` to `class CartonRepository : Repository<CartonDataRow>` (I do not think you need `ICartonRepository`, but you can use it if you want). Then

```
IRepository repository;
switch (rowType)
{
  case Carton:
    repository = new CartonRepository();
    break;
  case Pack:
    repository = new PackRepository();
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
interface IRepository<out T> where T : DataRow
{
  T Get(int key);
}
```

This requires C# 4.0 though.

Comment: The only part of this which requires .NET4.0 is the 'out' param declaring the typeparam 'T' as covariant. Which is not necessary for a solution to create a generic repository implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You require some sort of [Factory pattern](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/factory_method).

Following logic should go to Factory class

```
class RepositoryFactory
{
    IRepository<T>  Get(rowType)
    {
        IRepository<T> repository = default(IRepository<T>);
        switch (rowType)
        {
        case Carton:
            repository = new CartonRepository();
            break;
        case Pack:
            repository = new PackRepository();
            break;
        }

        return repository;
    }
}
```

You can further improve Get Method using [Dependency Injection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163739.aspx) or based on maintaining all repositories in [dictionary.](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/gilf/archive/2009/11/22/applying-strategy-pattern-instead-of-using-switch-statements.aspx)

Comment: +1 for Factory pattern mention alone => very useful knowledge and many schools don't mention it